# Zorich's Mathematical Analysis, Volume II

Tags: multivariable-calculus, reference-request, vector-analysis, book-recommendation, differential-forms

Springer just published a new English version of Vladmir Zorich's two-volume *Mathematical Analysis*. I was looking at the second volume. It seems to have sections on both Multivariable/Vector Calculus and Differential Forms and the basic of Differential Geometry.

I have meaning to read these topics to further my knowledge of Analysis (of one variable) and introduce myself to Differental Geometry for General Relativity since I'm a student of physics.

What is the general conception of the second volume of Zorich's book? Also, is reading the first volume a pre requisite to go to the second volume.

Thanks.

Comment: have you already checked the introduction (usually this is free content)?

Comment: From the Preface: “Chapters 9 and 10, with which this book begins, reproduce in compressed and generalized form, essentially all of the most important results that were obtained in the first part concerning continuous and differentiable functions. These chapters are starred and written as an appendix to Part 1. This appendix contains, however, many concepts that play a role in any exposition of analysis to mathematicians. The presence of these two chapters makes the second book formally independent of the first, ...

Comment: ... provided the reader is sufficiently well prepared to get by without the numerous examples and introductory considerations that, in the first part, preceded the formalism discussed here.”

Comment: And both volumes are very good!